# Find the page ranks of web pages

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Without damping, find the page ranks of the following webgraphs of three pages by determining their normalized eigenvectors for the eigenvalue of 1.

I don't know how to format this, but I'll do my best.

(a) 1 only goes to 3, 2 goes to 1 and 3, and 3 goes to 2

(b) 1 goes to 3, 2 goes to 1 and 3, 3 goes to 1

EDIT: I've added am imgur link since I have no clue how I'd write this in LaTex or text.
[image]

I do not understand how to set this up, the book and my professor were very vague in setting this up, as the book has two methods of solving this, but demonstrate these techniques using larger matrices, 6x6 and larger.

The answers are as follows;

(a) [1/5 2/5 2/5]^T

(b) [1/2 0 1/2]^T

Comment: You need to find the $1$-eigenvector of the transition matrix. Keep in mind that the matrix will not be symmetric. 
Maybe you have to use some theorems provided in you book to ease the computations of the stationary distribution.

Comment: @Zubzub Isn’t that pretty much what the first sentence of the question says to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working backwards from the two answers, I would guess that you build a transition matrix $P$ for the graphs assuming equal probabilities for the page transitions. An element $p_{ij}$ of the matrix gives the probability of jumping to page $i$ from page $j$, so you would have nonzero entries in the $j$th column in the rows that correspond to the pages that are directly linked by page $j$, with a probability equal to $1$ over the total number of pages linked by that page. You then compute the null space of $P-I$ and normalize the resulting vector so that its components add up to $1$.

For example, the matrix for the first graph is $$P=\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac12&0\\0&0&1\\1&\frac12&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Page 1 only goes to page 3, so the first column has a $1$ as its last element. Page 2 goes to 1 or 3 with equal probability, so there’s a $\frac12$ in each of those slots of the second column. Page 3 only goes to page 2, so there a lone $1$ in that column, too.

We then find an eigenvector of $1$ by row-reducing $P-I$: $$\begin{bmatrix}-1&\frac12&0\\0&-1&1\\1&\frac12&-1\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-\frac12\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ from which we can read the eigenvector $(1,2,2)$. Dividing this by the sum of its elements gives $\left(\frac15,\frac25,\frac25\right)$ as per the answer.